# Rendering BIM models

Tags: android, ios, rendering, autodesk

I've been looking at rendering BIM-models on iOS and Android and saw that Autodesk has API's for displaying them, but I'm not sure that it is possible to use this in an iOS or Android app.
So my question is: Do any BIM rendering libraries for Android and/or iOS exist yet?

Comment: yes the Autodesk Froge Viewer should work on Android apps, you just need a webcontrol to host it.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like there even is a sample project for Android. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the [Autodesk Froge Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/) should work on Android apps, you just need a webcontrol to host it.

Comment: What about iOS? :-)

Comment: the same idea should work, I believe this sample can help: https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/workflow-ios-view.and.data.api

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you!